# How can I know a Mongodb server is running with --auth on?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using nodejs and Mongodb JS driver mongodb-native.

But there seems no way for me to know whether the mongo server I connect need authentication, which means it's running with --auth on, so I can decide whether I should call db.authenticate method.

Have checked db, server and admin objects' properties, no one seems to indicate the --auth option.

Please help.

Comment: Why do you need to detect this? If it needs a password, you need to have configuration for that. If someone configured a password for your application, you call authenticate, if not, you don't.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense too, but it will weaken flexible operations. What I am trying to do is to access different database servers via one portal and try to do something on them, and different servers tend to have different configurations. Besides, knowing the server's configuration would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah there is no way to currently do this but I think it's a valid case. I suggest you open a feature request on https://jira.mongodb.org and vote it up so it might be included in a future release of the server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will log a feature request.